# Can't spot the error in Mergesort

Tags: c

l & h corresponds to the indices of the 1st & last elements in array a:-
The individual partition and merging functions are working well. Please explain the error occurring in the linking of the two functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void mergesort(int a[], int l, int h);
void merge (int a[], int l, int m, int h);
int main ()
{
    int a[] = {5,4,9,0,8,6,1,3,2,7}, i;
    mergesort (a, 0, 5);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf ("%d ", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
void mergesort(int a[], int l, int h) 
{
    if (l == h)
    return;
    int m = (l + h) / 2;
    mergesort (a, l, m);
    mergesort (a, m + 1, h);
    merge(a, l, m, h);
}
void merge (int a[], int l, int m, int h)
{
    int t[h - l + 1], i = l, j = m + 1, k = 0;
    while (i <= m && j <= h) {
        if (a[i] < a[j]){
            t[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        if (a[j] < a[i]) {
            t[k] = a[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (i != m) {
        while (i <= m) {
            t[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (j != h) {
        while (j <= h) {
            t[k] = a[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= (h - l); i++)
        a[l + i] = t[i];
    }
```

Instead of the desired output

```
0 4 5 6 8 9 1 3 2 7
```

(the elements 0 to 5 inclusive become sorted), it produces some garbage like

```
0 4 6 9 2686712 32 1 3 2 7
```

Comment: Welcome to SO !! Kindly format your code.

Comment: Can you at least explain why it doesn't work, input, output and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The lines `if (i != m)` and `if (j != h)` must be `if (i <= m)` and `if (j <= h)`.

Besides, you can omit them as well because they are redundant (leave only the `while` conditions).
Less code, less bugs.